# Get response custom headers for cross-origin request

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, rxjs, angular-http

I have an Angular2/4 application with a get request that has a response header with a key of 'X-Auth-Key'. When I call response.header I get the default headers and then I call response.headers.get('X-Auth-Token') I get null. Below is my code and a screenshot of the request from the Chrome Console (var url is defined elsewhere).

```
    getToken(id: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'X-Auth-User': id, 'X-Auth-Key': password });
    return this.http
        .get(url + 'auth', { headers: headers })
        .map(response => {
            let user: User = response.json() as User;

            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ user: user, token: response.headers.get('X-Auth-Token') }));

            return user;
        })
   }// Get authorization token
```

[image]

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but I appreciate any help

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server must be configured to send an [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) that includes "`X-Auth-Key`" in its value if you want your requesting frontend JavaScript code to be allowed to access the `X-Auth-Key` response header value.

If the response includes no value for the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, the only response headers that browsers will let you access from client-side JavaScript in your web app are `Cache-Control`,
`Content-Language`,
`Content-Type`,
`Expires`,
`Last-Modified`
and 
`Pragma`.

See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name for the spec on that.

Comment: So even though I am receiving the header I need, I can't access it?

Comment: Correct—but more precisely, even though *the browser* is receiving the header you need (and you can even see it in browser devtools) that doesn’t mean the browser will automatically let your frontend JavaScript code access the value. Browsers block your frontend code from accessing that header value unless the server response includes an Access-Control-Expose-Headers that allows is. That’s a requirement of the CORS protocol, as documented in the Fetch spec.

Comment: Thanks! That clears things up a lot. I thought CORS just wouldn't allow the header come through, that why when I saw it, I was confused as to why I couldn't then use it.

Comment: Yeah, the CORS protocol never blocks servers from actually sending anything; instead it only causes *browsers* to block or allow your frontend code from actually being able to access whatever responses a server sends. The way it works is that servers send the same responses as they usually do, regardless—but just include additional headers to indicate how browsers should behave. Based on the absence or presence of those additional headers in the responses, and their values, browsers then either block or allow your frontend code from accessing the responses.